# Set PHP varibles on button press without using POST or GET

Tags: javascript, php

I need to set 3 PHP variables on a button press, but the problem is **I can't** use POST or GET to do it due to it refreshing the page which breaks my JavaScript code as it includes an onClick event listener.

What I want my code to do exactly is, on a button press set 3 variables, `$title`, `$description` and `$button_value`. When the button is pressed it also sets off the JavaScript code to display a box with some information that is the 3 PHP variables.

Is there anyway to get around this issue or would I just have to rewrite my JavaScript code to work with POST/GET? I'm new to PHP and JavaScript so apologies for my incompetence.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understand how these are connected.  Once its result is sent to the browser, your PHP code is finished.  It only starts running again when a new request is received. The only reason to send something to PHP is so the PHP can send a new page back.  What are you going to do with those variables?

Comment: @TimRoberts The variables are set on the button press, so I don't have to rewrite the information box for each button. The reason why Javascript is involved in this is because it doesnt run when the page refreshed due to me using POST or GET :/

Comment: If you want information to be retained beyond a single request, then you need to look at using sessions.  That's what they're for.  Remember that web exchanges are all independent: a request gets a response, then that exchange is OVER.  If you need to maintain a session, then you either need to send an id with every request, or you need to use a session.

Comment: I think the problem was me not understanding fully how POST worked on PHP, sorry for the incompetence. I think I'll have to rewrite a part of my website then. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run some PHP code while clicking the button and don't want to refresh it, then you can send [ajax request](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) to your server using javascript. You can also update your page dynamically using the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with PHP + JS, and refreshing the whole page is not an option, what you need is an AJAX call that will fire on your onClick().

AJAX refreshes just a part of your page.

It will send data to your PHP file, you can re-set your variables there as you need, and then there will be a response. This response you can then parse in your JS.

Basic structure should be like this:

```
onClick() -> .ajax() -> PHP script -> response -> process response in JS
```